# Chrome (and chromecast) playback stops after a few seconds

Tags: google-chrome, chromecast, aac

I have no idea where can I actually get help for this, so I'm hoping I'll get some pointers on where should I post my issue.

So we're supporting a radioplayer application that lets you play streams on chromecast devices. We've received more and more reports of streams stopping after a few seconds.

Inspecting the chromecast receiver application we found an error:

```
error: MediaError {code: 3, message: "PIPELINE_ERROR_DECODE: Format conversion failed."}
```

Ok, so it has an issue with decoding the stream. Just to keep the fun in funeral it turns out that it works on a chromecast gen1, but not on a chromecast gen3 or a home mini.

So we did what every normal developer would do: <strike>gave up and went to work at McDonalds</strike> created a sample webpage, with the streams (to leave out all the mess that comes with casting stuff). Tested this page in different browsers and browser versions: works everywhere except chrome. And not just chrome. If your chrome version is 66 or below, happy days. If its 67 or newer, the playback will stop. In the browser we get a slightly different error message, but since stops pretty much at the very same point where the chromecast does... I seem to see a common factor there.
Here is the sample page: http://chromecast.radioplayer.aerian.org/test.html

To tell a couple of radio stations to go and fix their streams would be feasible... but we're talking about potentially 50-90 stations, who's streams are otherwise working, except on a chromecast.

Is this a bug? Is this a feature?
If its a bug, where should a raise it? If its a feature would you like onions with your burger?

Comment: I would recommend having a look at chrome://media-internals/ and see if you spot anything in the logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've raised a bug report with chromium, turns out it's a bug. It's being fixed in V75. More details here: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=956027#c7